# Recursive CTE for URL path generation

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We have a parent child relationship for pages in our content management system.  The table is as follows

| ContentID | Parent | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | This Page |
| 2 | 1 | That Page |
| 3 | 0 | Another Page |
| 4 | 3 | Child of Another |
| 5 | 4 | Child of child |

A parent of 0 indicates the ultimate parent.

I want to output just the parents of a given contentid in a path.  As an example, the output for ContentID = 5 would be:

```
/another-page/child-of-another/
```

I've tried many recursive CTE examples that generate breadcrumbs and such like, but they always output the whole path:

```
/another-page/child-of-another/child-of-child/
```

I have a function to replace the spaces in the URL, so I'm just interested in the SQL to achieve the above.

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Comment: It's easier for us to help you with what you've tried if you show us the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method, using an rCTE and `STRING_AGG`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (ContentID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                            Parent int,
                            Title varchar(50));
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable (Parent, Title)
VALUES(0,'This Page'),
      (1,'That Page'),
      (0,'Another Page'),
      (3,'Child of Another'),
      (4,'Child of child');
GO

DECLARE @ID int = 5;

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT ContentID,
           Parent,
           Title,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.YourTable
    WHERE ContentID = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YT.ContentID,
           YT.Parent,
           YT.Title,
           r.level+1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN rCTE r ON YT.ContentID = r.Parent)
SELECT '/' + STRING_AGG(REPLACE(Title,' ','-'),'/') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Level DESC) + '/' AS Path
FROM rCTE
WHERE ContentID != @ID;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

An alternative method, without using `STRING_AGG`, and instead using an additional `JOIN` in the rCTE:

```sql
DECLARE @ID int = 5;

WITH rCTE AS(
    SELECT YT.ContentID,
           YT.Parent,
           CONVERT(varchar(8000),'/' + YT.Title) AS Title,
           1 AS Level
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN dbo.YourTable P ON YT.ContentID = P.Parent
    WHERE P.ContentID = @ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YT.ContentID,
           YT.Parent,
           CONVERT(varchar(8000),'/' + YT.Title + r.Title),
           r.Level + 1
    FROM dbo.YourTable YT
         JOIN rCTE r ON YT.ContentID = r.Parent)
SELECT TOP 1 REPLACE(Title,' ','-') + '/' AS Path
FROM rCTE
ORDER BY Level DESC;
```